# How to split string array to 2-dimension char array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a string array, for example:

```
a = ['123', '456', '789']
```

I want to split it to form a 2-dimension char array:

```
b = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

I'm using

```
[[element for element in line] for line in array]
```

to achieve my goal but found it not easy to read, is there any built-in function or any readable way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like a job for `map`:

```
>>> a = ['123', '456', '789']
>>> map(list, a)
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

---

**Relevant documentation:**

- [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)
- [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)

Answer (score 4):

you could do something like:

```
first_list = ['123', '456', '789']
other_weirder_list = [list(line) for line in first_list]
```

Your solution isn't that bad, but you might do something like this or the `map` suggestion by arashajii.

Answer (score 3):

`map(list, array)` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`:

```
>>> a
['123', '456', '789']
>>> map(list, a)
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

Although I really don't see why you'd need to do this (unless you plan on editing one specific character in the string?). Strings behave similarly to lists.

Answer (score 0):

First I tried `e.split('')`, but I get `ValueError: empty separator`.

Try this:

```
a = ['123', '456', '789']
b = [list(e) for e in a]
b
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```